# IBM Websphere Datapower Xi52

Tags: ibm-datapower

I really appreciate your response to my following question.
Is there any way I can send SOMA request against xml-mgmt interface to see/check the probe status on different domian? if there are turned on/off?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the "show domain" command shows status of all domains probes.

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/management">
  <env:Body>
    <dp:request domain="default">
      <dp:get-status class="DomainStatus" /></dp:request>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

You can then parse the respons as XML and get status from XPath:

```
//*[local-name()='DomainStatus']/*[local-name()='Domain'][text()='test-domain']/following-sibling::*[local-name()='ProbeEnabled']/text()
```